# Android: animateLayoutChanges(false) programmatically giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

*This is not duplicate of 'animateLayoutChanges programmatically'.*

I **want** the default animation effects on my view changes **except** from the fade out effect on removing the objects. I cannot use `disableTransitionType()` because it was added in API 16. All I could think of was disabling the `android:animateLayoutChanges` to `false`, remove the view and setting it again to `true`. In my `recyclerView` I thought of removing the animation by `holder.rootView.setLayoutTansition(null)`. But unfortunately it is giving me `NullPointerException`.

A part of my code is something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SavedMessagePackage current = data.get(position);
    final String message = current.message;
    holder.message.setText(message);
    holder.message.setMaxLines(2);
    holder.message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.button.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.message.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                holder.message.setText(message);
            }
            else if (holder.button.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                holder.root_view.setLayoutTransition(null); // NullPointerException
                holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.message.setMaxLines(2);
                holder.root_view.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
            }
        }
    });
    holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you assign `root_view`?

Comment: @tynn I did assign but your comment made me go back and look at it again. I found my mistake. I had a global variable `root_view` as well and I forgot to write `this.root_view`. You can answer it. I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could have `holder` or `root_view` being null, but since holder was accessed successfully before, so `root_view` is null.

Therefore it's most likely you didn't assign `holder.root_view` before.